# Reducing size of dedication

Tags: fontsize, koma-script

I'm writing my thesis in the LyX template that's based on Koma-Script book ("scrbook.cls"). I'm using `\dedication` to add a quote as the motto.

Is there a way to make the font size of this text smaller?

Comment: You can specify the size as an argument of `\dedication`. The font size is hard coded in `scrbook` to `\Large`

Comment: Would that be `\dedication[font=small]`? Is there a way to change the the settings for `\dedication` font size in the preamble? - LyX makes it hard to edit code in the template ...

Comment: In the preamble you can do `\makeatletter\renewcommand{\dedication}[1]{\gdef\@dedication{\normalsize#1}}\make‌​atother`

Answer (score 5):

**Update:**

In the next release of KOMA script new font elements are implemented `titlehead`, `author`, `date`, `publishers`, **`dedication`**

Source (German): http://www.komascript.de/releasesvn

(The current version is v3.11b)

---

**First answer:**

The font size of `\dedication` inside KOMA is hard coded. The relevant part of the code is:

```
  \ifx\@dedication\@empty \else
    \next@tpage\null\vfill
    {\centering \Large \@dedication \par}%
    \vskip \z@ \@plus3fill
    \if@twoside \next@tpage\cleardoubleemptypage \fi
  \fi
```

You can redefine the default definition of `\dedication` to add some font information. This can be achieved by:

```
\makeatletter
 \renewcommand{\dedication}[1]{%
    \gdef\@dedication{\normalsize #1}}
\ma‌​ke‌​atother
```

---

As a first KOMA-Implementation you can use the following definition which allows the font size of `dedication` to manipulate by `setkomafont`:

```
\setcounter{errorcontextlines}{999}
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\newkomafont{dedication}{\Large}
\xpatchcmd{\maketitle}{\Large \@dedication}{\scr@fnt@dedication \@dedication}{}{}
\makeatother

\setkomafont{dedication}{\small}
\begin{document}
\author{foo}
\title{foobar}
\dedication{foobarfoo}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe one should make a feature request for a koma-font »dedication« so that `\setkomafont{dedication}{...}` would work...

Comment: @cgnieder: I dropped an email to Markus Kohm.