# Set author font in scrartcl

Tags: formatting, titles, koma-script

I've got a document using the scrartcl and fontspec packages, like so:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
```

I'm setting the fonts using the following:

```
\setmainfont[Ligatures={Common,TeX}]{Minion Pro}
\setsansfont{Myriad Pro}
\setmonofont[Scale=0.8]{Consolas}
```

Then creating a title:

```
\title{Document Title}
\author{Author Name}
\date{}
\maketitle
```

This works great, however while the title is set in my sans serif font, the author appears in the main font. What do I need to do to get the author to appear in the sans serif font as well?

Comment: See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113877/reducing-size-of-dedication/115970#115970

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3):

As soon as the current `KOMA-Script` version (3.11b) is updated, the following addition to your preamble should suffice:

```
\setkomafont{author}{\sffamily}
```

With version 3.11b, one may use the [`xpatch`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch) package to add `\sffamily` to the code responsible for typesetting the author names.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures={Common,TeX}]{Minion Pro}
\setsansfont{Myriad Pro}
\setmonofont[Scale=0.8]{Consolas}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\maketitle}{% with the `titlepage` class option
  \@author
}{%
  \sffamily\@author
}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\@maketitle}{% without the `titlepage` class optipn
  \@author
}{%
  \sffamily\@author
}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{Document Title}
\author{Author Name}
\date{}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]